# what does `find pattern dir` do?

Tags: find

When I search for some files under a dir, I run

```
find dir -name pattern
```

But I find that the following will return all the files under `dir`, regardless what `pattern` is:

```
find pattern dir
```

is it just like `tree dir`? 
Why is it?

Comment: find command has operators, test , actions and unusual filenames, see the following tutorials: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` can take many dirs as arguments:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -name pattern
```

so `find patern dir` just lists everything inside two **directories**: *pattern* and *dir*.

Answer (score 1):

In find, when you use the `-name` that means only output files with that name as a result

Comment: What does `find pattern dir` do?

Comment: as in `find foo.sh /`? where `foo.sh` is the file being looked for and `/` is the directory?

Comment: It list all the the contents and subcontents of `dir` here. `pattern` doesn't matter.